# Hyperledger Fabric RAM utilization with multiple organizations

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ram

I am running some tests on fabric.

I have one experiment where I run a single organization of 16 peers and invoke some functions on each peer. After I do another experiment with 8 organizations with 2 peers each and invoke some functions on each peer.

One of the measured metrics is the difference in RAM usage of all containers before and after all invoke functions.

In the case of one organization I get about 1GB extra RAM usage, in case of 8 organizations I get about 6GB extra RAM usage. Does anyone know the reason for this behaviour ?
The invoke functions all store the same data in the blockchain.

I have tried with 2 organizations and 8 peers per each and I get the same result. That is as soon as the number of organizations is increased the RAM usage skyrockets.